# How to get the Preview image using advImage plugin in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce

HI ,
 i am using Tinymce with advimage plugin in my rails application.

I have doubt that When i click on the Insert/Edit iamge in the Tinymce a popup window comes and in the appearance tab the preview is not shown

How to get the preview image ?? in the Appearance tab

Answer (score 0):

There are two "previews" in the Advanced Image plugin dialog. The first is the preview of the image you have selected. The second is to allow you to visualise what the style changes you make (for instance border, alignment) would look like and uses an "sample" image.

I assume what you would like to see is your selected image displayed instead of the "sample" image. To achieve this, you will need to alter the **advimage** plugin, which is bundled with TinyMCE, to use the currently selected image instead of the default (sample.gif).

One thing to consider is that if your end user selects a large image, then they wouldn't be able to see the application of the style changes within the small preview window.